# Why $ {-1\choose 3}=-1$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Having the following definition:

$$\binom \alpha k = \frac{\alpha^{\underline k}}{k!} = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots 1}\tag{1}$$

Why $\bbox[1px,border:1px solid black]{{-1\choose 3}=-1}$? I know that $\bbox[1px,border:1px solid black]{{-1\choose 3}=-1}$ because of the following identity:

$${-n \choose r}=(-1)^r{n+r-1 \choose r}$$

Then I'd just need to compute:

$${-1 \choose 3}=(-1)^3{1+3-1 \choose 3}=-1\times1=-1$$

But upon using $(1)$, I'd have:

$${-1 \choose 3} = \frac{-1(-1-1)(-1-2)(-1-3+1)}{3(2)(1)}=\frac{-1(-2)(-3)(-3)}{6}=\frac{18}{6}=3$$

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I suppose I should do $-1(-1-1)(-1-2)(-1-3+1)$ until I reach $k$ which is $3$.

Comment: $\displaystyle{-1\choose n}=(-1)^n$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have one factor too many in the numerator: it should be

$$\binom{-1}3=\frac{(-1)^{\underline 3}}{3!}=\frac{(-1)(-1-1)(-1-2)}{3!}=\frac{-6}6=-1\;.$$

Comment: Yes. But is it possible to understand this from that definition?

Comment: @Vÿska: It’s exactly what the definition says. When $\alpha=-1$ and $k=3$, $\alpha-k+1=-1-3+1=-3$, not $-4$.

Comment: I don't get it. So instead of reaching $k$, I should reach $k-1$?

Comment: @Vÿska: Count the factors: there are $k$ of them, from $\alpha-0$, $\alpha-1$, and so on down to $\alpha-k+1=\alpha-(k-1)$.

Comment: That's it. It makes more sense to see $\alpha - (k-1)$. This way, it seems that $(k-1)$ is entirely on the plot. Seeing $a-k+1$ is like $k$ was the protagonist and $1$ have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Vÿska: I wondered if that was where you were getting hung up. I’m glad that we got it sorted.